# Unable to Install Tensorflow on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to install tensorflow on Windows using Anaconda but keep getting this error:  ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib'

I was using the below code:

```
 C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 
 C:> activate tensorflow
 (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

And I also tried using

```
 C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

And it said 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I have both Python 3.5 and 3.6.

Could someone help me with this? 
Thank you!

Comment: There are some suggestions on this GitHub thread: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/146

Comment: Thank you! I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the **html5lib** folder from: https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/tree/master/html5lib.
Find the **html5lib** folder(s) (if many environments) and replace the files inside the folder(s).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the missing environment variable for python I guess. When you were adding env var did you add both the Anaconda root folder and the Anaconda/Scripts folder? If not you need to do so.

Here you can see how you can properly: [Install Tensorflow in Anaconda - 4min Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNWQN_g_ZsI)